# A question regarding に従って

Tags: grammar

> そして、施設内で生活するに従っての約束事、その約束事を破った場合のペナルティー、そういうことも記されていた。

I've come upon unusual (at least for me) usage of に従って and can't figure out how it works.
As far as I know, に従って should be used with verbs when there's some gradual change or be used with a noun in the sense of "according to". However, neither of these meanings seem to apply in this case. I tried to search for more meanings or some exceptions, but wasn't able to find any. My best guess with translating 施設内で生活するに従っての約束事 is something like "rules you should follow while staying at facility", but even if it's correct, I don't understand how に従って works here.

Could someone tell me how to interpret this に従って?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

”〜するに従って“  is an idiom and means  “upon doing 〜”.     It’s different from normal usage of 従う which means to obey.